# Matlab figures lagging

Tags: matlab, matlab-figure

Last week, Matlab crashed on my computer and gave a message regarding the figure driver or engine being changed (unfortunately, I do not remember exactly what it said). Ever since then, all of my figures have been extremely laggy and have appeared to have a lower resolution.

Has anyone run into this or have any troubleshooting advice?

Comment: what is the output of `rendererinfo(gca)`? if it uses opengl software, try typing `opengl hardware` to use opengl hardware rendering again

Comment: Yes, it is using OpenGL Software. However, when I try that opengl command, I get the following error:

`Error using opengl
Changing the OpenGL implementation at the command line is not supported. Instead, specify the implementation when starting MATLAB.`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to solve this by creating a startup.m file in my MATLAB directory (located in Documents in my case). This file is called every time MATLAB is initialized. In this file I typed: `opengl('save','hardware')`. After staring MATLAB once with this startup.m file, I was able to delete this line of code from that file (this command changes opengl permanently, unless it is manually changed back).

Alternatively, I could have typed `opengl hardware` into the startup.m file. In this case this line of code would need to be left in the startup file.